# How do i change column name in a dataframe in python pandas

Tags: python, pandas

im new to python, i used to code...

```
StoreGrouper= DonHenSaless.groupby('Store')
StoreGrouperT= StoreGrouper["SalesDollars"].agg(np.sum)
StoreGrouperT.rename(columns={SalesDollars:TotalSalesDollars})
```

to group stores and sum by the SalesDollars then rename SalesDollars to TotalSalesDollars. it outputted the following error...

NameError: name 'SalesDollars' is not defined

I also tried using quotes

```
StoreGrouper= DonHenSaless.groupby('Store')
StoreGrouperT= StoreGrouper["SalesDollars"].agg(np.sum)
StoreGrouperT= StoreGrouperT.rename(columns={'SalesDollars':'TotalSalesDollars'})
```

This output the error: rename() got an unexpected keyword argument 'columns'

Here is my df
[df](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jppGl.png)

Comment: you're probably working with a Series, rather than a DataFrame after `.agg` - what happens if you display it or call `type()`?

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples)

Comment: Thank you @ti7 that worked didn't realize they were series and not dataframes :)

Answer (score 1):

In order to rename a column you need quotes so it would be:

```
StoreGrouperT.rename(columns={'SalesDollars':'TotalSalesDollars'})
```

Also I usually assign it a variable

```
StoreGrouperT = StoreGrouperT.rename(columns={'SalesDollars':'TotalSalesDollars'})
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the pandas rename option to change the column name. You can also use inplace as true if you want your change to get reflected to the dataframe rather than saving it again on the df variable

```
df.rename(columns={'old_name':'new_name'}, inplace=True)
```